# Create jdt look like custom tool tip for GEF canvas objects

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, tooltip, eclipse-jdt

I have a graphical representation for my model, and I want to implement a tooltip that look like jdt tooltip in the following :
  - the tooltip shows up when hover over the object in the canvas
  - being able to click on the tooltip window to focus, and scroll bar is there if needed.
  - Ability to resize the tooltip window after the user change focus to it
  - being able to assign command with F2 keybind to pop up the tooltip window (I know how to create command, and how to associate keybind with it)
  - Ability to have hyperlinks in the tooltip text ( optional )

I do not know from where to start.
 Which eclipse interfaces/classes to implement, extensions to add, adaptors to support.

I tried to find a work through tutorial but I could not.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of what you describe is specific to the Eclipse Text editor and JDT code so won't be available in a Canvas so you would have to write your own code.

You can create a tooltip based on `org.eclipse.jface.window.ToolTip`. If the tooltip contains `StyledText` you can create hyperlinks.

There is an example of a fairly elaborate custom tooltip [Here](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.jface.snippets/Eclipse%20JFace%20Snippets/org/eclipse/jface/snippets/window/Snippet020CustomizedControlTooltips.java)

What Eclipse does when the tooltip is clicked is open a new normal window of exactly the same size and contents over the tooltip and close the tooltip.

Comment: Would you elaborate a little about how to start using ToolTip ?  
What should I do after extending ToolTip class, so when I hover with mouse on canvas object, my class will get invoked

Comment: Added link to official JFace tooltip example